# How to use dispatch of okhttp-MockWebServer? Cannot inherit from final 'okhttp3.Dispatcher'

Tags: java, kotlin, mocking, okhttp, mockwebserver

I want to use the okhttp-MockWebServer not with the normal queue but with the Dispatcher as described in the [Readme-section](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/README.md#dispatcher).

The example requires one to inherit from `Dispatcher` which is not possible because `okhttp3.Dispatcher` is a final class.

Is this a regression introduced by the Kotlin-rewrite of okhttp? (Kotlin makes classes final by default)
Or is there a different and new intended way of setting up something similar to a Dispatcher?

(x-posted as a gh-issue: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/8130 )

Comment: Close-reason "Lacks clarity or detail". What is unclear? You can't inherit from a final class and therefore the example code from the provided readme-section doesn't compile. I am asking how to achieve the dispatching-feature with this new version of MockWebServer, if this is possible. ("No it is not possible, the feature was removed" is also a valid answer to this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `okhttp3.mockwebserver.Dispatcher`. `okhttp3.Dispatcher` is not for MockWebServer.

Comment: Perfect solution. I hate it when jvm-libraries do that, but it's a trap I should have watched out for. I will edit my wrong import into the question so this QA is readable without going to github.